# How to open Generative Shape Design Workbench in Catia V5 using Python WinCom API

Tags: python, windows, pywin32, cad, catia

I am using the pypiwin32 Python API for Catia V5 to try and perform some operations on a surface, operations that are in the Generative Shape Design workbench. I am referencing this code snippet I found [here](http://ifcuriousthenlearn.com/blog/2015/06/10/catia-and-simulia-scripting-and-automation-with-python/) of someone opening the Analysis workbench.

```
# Activate the Generative Structural Analysis (GPS) Workbench
PartDoc=CATIA.ActiveDocument
CATIA.StartWorkbench ("GPSCfg")
CATIA.ActiveDocument.Analysis.Import(PartDoc)
```

I have tried changing the argument of the StartWorkBench method to "GSD" and "Generative Shape Design". What does "GPSCfg" even stand for? How do I open and interact with the Generative Shape Design workbench using this API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic word you are looking for is "CATShapeDesignWorkbench"

The method that reveals this word for any workbench is CATIA.GetWorkbenchId().

Comment: Thank you for response, that worked. How do I access the tools of the open workbench?

Comment: I want to extract a surface.

Comment: Try recording a macro and look at it. When it does work it can help you learn the API. It will be in VB but you should be able to use the methods to Python easily.